# How to replace tokens in a classList incrementally?

Tags: javascript, class, replace, token, contains

I'd like to find a way to replace the token 'c1' with 'c2', replace 'c2' with 'c3', etc. using fewer lines of code.

Currently, I'm going through each  element with forEach, like so:

```
carsLeft.forEach(carLeft => moveCarLeft(carLeft))
```

And then to move the element one space over to the left, I enter into a switch statement to reassign a class to it:

```
switch(true) {
        case carLeft.classList.contains('c1'):
            carLeft.classList.replace('c1', 'c2')
            break
        case carLeft.classList.contains('c2'):
            carLeft.classList.replace('c2', 'c3')
            break
        case carLeft.classList.contains('c3'):
            carLeft.classList.replace('c3', 'c4')
            break
    }
```

I was wondering if there is a way to use regular expressions to simplify the switch statement into something like this:

```
carLeft.classList.replace(`c\d`, `c\d+`)
```

...or perhaps another way aside from using regular expressions. Thank you for taking the time to read this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use regex with String.replace, but this is [DOMTokenList.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/replace), which doesn't support regex.

Comment: You could iterate through the class list and basically `.map()` each class to a replacement.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use CSS rules and add/remove classes on a parent element to effectively effect the changes you're attempting with rules based on the state of the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    if (carLeft.classList.contains("c"+i)) {
        carLeft.classList.replace("c"+i, "c"+(i+1));
        break;
    }
}
```